# My dash subplots are too flat. How can I enlarge the Y axis?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have used python dash to make some subplots but when I run it it is like this

[image]

You can see that the Y axis is too small compared to the X axis.
I don't want to make them equal since the values from both axis are quite different but for visualization purposes it should be a bit more square
like

[image]

Notice that in the second one the Y is more elongated

How can I do this?

Comment: Which class are you using to construct the figure with the subplots? If for example you're using px.scatter from plotly express, then you can just set the width and height parameters to your liking. [link to documentation](https://plotly.com/python/setting-graph-size/)

Comment: I am not using plotly express but `import plotly.graph_objects as go` and     
`from plotly.subplots import make_subplots`

Comment: @MattSmith I got what I wanted adding `fig.update_layout(height=800)`. Not really sure what 800 means but it looks better now. Thanks

Comment: it's 800 pixels. No problem